# Why does this Sorbet error count as a dynamic constant reference?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I'm getting the following error in Sorbet:

```
lib/guardian.rb:24: Dynamic constant references are unsupported https://srb.help/5001
    24 |      self.class::MIN_AUTH || raise("Minimum auth must be specified")
```

The Guardian class has the following structure

```
class Guardian
  MIN_AUTH = AuthLevel.new(:STRONG)
  # ...

  def min_auth
    self.class::MIN_AUTH || raise("Minimum auth must be specified")
  end
end
```

It is designed to so that it can change on child objects. It's also designed such that if it's not specified on a child object we hear about it. I'm interested to know why such a design pattern is (implied) bad practice. Should I skip the constant and just define it in the helper method instead: `get_min_auth`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I skip the constant and just define it in the helper method instead: `get_min_auth`?

Yep, that's exactly it.

```rb
# typed: true
class AuthLevel < T::Struct
  const :level, Symbol
end

class Guardian
  def get_min_auth
    AuthLevel.new(level: :STRONG)
  end

  def min_auth
    get_min_auth || raise("Minimum auth must be specified")
  end
end
```

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20AuthLevel%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20const%20%3Alevel%2C%20Symbol%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20Guardian%0A%20%20def%20get_min_auth%0A%20%20%20%20AuthLevel.new(level%3A%20%3ASTRONG)%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20def%20min_auth%0A%20%20%20%20get_min_auth%20%7C%7C%20raise(%22Minimum%20auth%20must%20be%20specified%22)%0A%20%20end%0Aend)

To really drive home why using methods are better here: you can use an abstract method to require that child classes implement the method. There's no way to require that child classes define a constant. This would make your entire example basically go away, because you would no longer need to `raise`. It would turn into a static type error:

```rb
# typed: true
class AuthLevel < T::Struct
  const :level, Symbol
end

class Guardian
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Helpers
  abstract!

  sig {abstract.returns(AuthLevel)}
  def min_auth
  end
end

class MyGuardian < Guardian
end
```

[→ View on sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20AuthLevel%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20const%20%3Alevel%2C%20Symbol%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20Guardian%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AHelpers%0A%20%20abstract!%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Babstract.returns(AuthLevel)%7D%0A%20%20def%20min_auth%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20MyGuardian%20%3C%20Guardian%0Aend)

---

> I'm interested to know why such a design pattern is (implied) bad practice.

Sorbet works in phases. First, it learns about all classes/modules/constants in a codebase. Then, it learns about all methods on those classes/modules. Then it learns about the types on those methods. And finally, it learns about the types of local variables in those methods.

When Sorbet is looking to see whether `(...)::MIN_AUTH` is a constant that actually exists, it knows **nothing except the constants** that have been defined so far, not the methods and not the local variables. `self` is essentially a local variable, and `.class` is a method that could have been overridden on a child class. Since it knows about neither local variables nor methods, it reports a dynamic constant reference. `self.class` is an "arbitrary expression," not a static constant.

So maybe the next question is: **why does Sorbet impose this seemingly arbitrary ordering** of resolving constants first? The two biggest reasons:

- **Speed**. It requires less analysis to say "this is a dynamic constant reference" and ask the programmer to refactor the code than it does to allow cyclic references. Given that there's a relatively easy refactoring (that you mention), this seems like a worthwile tradeoff to make every subsequent type check run faster.
- **Readability**. `self.class::MIN_AUTH` is essentially dynamic dispatch via Ruby's constant resolution algorithms. And in fact, constant resolution is in many ways harder to understand than method resolution, because it's affected by both module nesting and the inheritance hierarchy (whereas method lookup is only affected by inheritance). Relying on a complex lookup and dispatch is harder to read than just using methods, which people are more familiar with (especially coming from other languages to Ruby).

Comment: Such a helpful answer right from the horse’s mouth. Thanks for all the excellent work you guys have done on this @jez it’s a fantastic addition to Ruby. While I have you can I enquire aS to whether you use (and can share) a guardfile or similar that runs Sorbet in the background? I’m running it manually but I’d love to split pane it and have it run “on save” alongside my tests

Comment: I rarely use Sorbet. Almost all of my work is on the C++ code that implements Sorbet. There are a lot of people who use Sorbet in our Slack community (https://sorbet.org/slack); I'd encourage you to join and ask there.